# Mysql Query Replication status

Tags: sql, wamp, database-replication

I'm currently running a WAMP installation with a master/ slave replication process in place.

As a part of the System Admin dashboard I wish to display the current status of the replication between the Master and Slave instances of my database.

What query can I run on the slave/ master that returns the current status of the replication?

Cheers
Jordan

Comment: You should be able to find this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-administration-status.html

Comment: Have a look at the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` command